# how to set following fonts as by default fonts for Latex document

Tags: amsfonts

how to set following fonts as by default fonts for LaTeX document
`\textbf` new times roman
 for Headings

`\textrm` for text

`\mathrm`  for math equations

plz help me out

Thanks in advance
Muhammad ibrar Hussain

Comment: Welcome! `\textrm` is default for text. `\mathrm` for which parts of maths? Please provide a complete minimal document as the best solution will depend a great deal on your class and any packages you are using to customise headings.

Comment: Making all mathematical content in your report roman is really not a good idea.